# C# - list box events doesn't work anymore

Tags: c#, events, listbox

I don't know how to put this, It's very strange to me! 
until couple days a go this code worked fine for me but now It doesn't work anymore :

```
private void lst_CustomerName_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ds3.Tables["T"].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        string str = lst_CustomerName.SelectedItems[0].ToString();
        txt_CustomerID.Text = ds3.Tables["T"].Rows[lst_CustomerName.SelectedIndex]["Id"].ToString();
        txt_CustomerName.Text = str;
        lst_CustomerName.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

not only this event but I tested these events to and they don't work either :

```
lst_ProductName_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

and

```
lst_ProductName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

I put some break point in it to see if it goes there or not (I mean before my if) but It's not going there at all!
whats the problem? am I doing something stupid?

**edit :**

from designer.cs :

```
this.lst_ProductName.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.lst_ProductName.ItemHeight = 19;
            this.lst_ProductName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(888, 374);
            this.lst_ProductName.Name = "lst_ProductName";
            this.lst_ProductName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(259, 99);
            this.lst_ProductName.TabIndex = 29;
            this.lst_ProductName.DoubleClick += new System.EventHandler(this.lst_ProductName_DoubleClick);
```

from my code :

```
private void lst_ProductName_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ds6.Tables["T"].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        string str = lst_ProductName.SelectedItems[0].ToString();
        txt_ID_product.Text = ds6.Tables["T"].Rows[lst_ProductName.SelectedIndex]["Id"].ToString();
        txt_product_name.Text = str;
        lst_ProductName.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to recreate your problem but it looks like it works for me.
Do you have the same issue with code below? If not then can you modify so the problem occurs?
There may be something more what you are doing and what is causing it.

Whole program:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ListBoxNotWorking
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private System.Windows.Forms.ListBox lst_ProductName;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txt_product_name;
        public Form1()
        {
            this.lst_ProductName = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
            this.txt_product_name = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();

            this.lst_ProductName.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.lst_ProductName.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
            "item1",
            "item2",
            "item3"});
            this.lst_ProductName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(81, 50);
            this.lst_ProductName.Name = "lst_ProductName";
            this.lst_ProductName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(120, 95);
            this.lst_ProductName.TabIndex = 0;
            this.lst_ProductName.DoubleClick += new System.EventHandler(this.lst_ProductName_DoubleClick);

            this.txt_product_name.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(86, 189);
            this.txt_product_name.Name = "txt_product_name";
            this.txt_product_name.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.txt_product_name.TabIndex = 1;

            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
            this.Controls.Add(this.txt_product_name);
            this.Controls.Add(this.lst_ProductName);
        }
        private void lst_ProductName_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string str = lst_ProductName.SelectedItems[0].ToString();
            //  txt_ID_product.Text = ds6.Tables["T"].Rows[lst_ProductName.SelectedIndex]["Id"].ToString();
            txt_product_name.Text = str;
            lst_ProductName.Visible = false;
        }
    }

    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```